# After installing Fedora Linux using Asus vivobook, cannot access OS

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, windows-8.1

3 days ago, I installed Fedora on my Asus Vivobook s551. After the installation, I could not enter either the Linux OS nor the original Windows 8.1 OS!

I need to access my original operating system, Windows 8.1, and my files! I could however see my files and all of my partitions using gParted Live.

I googled a lot and didn't find any useful way to fix my problem!!
notes:

1. I can't see my hdd in my boot menu options (I could see my files through gparted linux distro but couldn't from windows mini using hirens bootcd)
2. I disabled the secure boot same thing..
3. I tried to fixmbr and everything you could imagine with the windows 8.1 DVD but it did not work. When trying to reset or refresh my installation, says my hard drive is locked!! I couldn't do anything with my Win 8.1 DVD!
4. I don't want to lose my original windows copy because cant afford buying a new windows copy...I found a .wim file in my recovery partition..could this help???

Any help would be grateful; thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your question fixing all the grammar and spelling issues.

The best solution in your case is to do the following:

**PART ONE**

1. Take out hard drive
2. Insert into external enclosure
3. Plug into a new PC
4. **CRITICAL STEP -- DO NOT SKIP!!** Copy all files on the hard drive to the new PC
5. Remove hard drive from enclosure and insert hard drive back into old PC
6. Boot into gParted Live using the Live CD
7. **WARNING! ENSURE YOU BACKED EVERYTHING UP TO OTHER PC IN STEP 4 ABOVE
   BEFORE PROCEEDING WITH STEP 7!!**
   WIPE entire drive removing ALL partitions and data making it completely blank.

**PART TWO:**

1. Install Windows back onto the newly wiped HDD using the Windows 8.1 DVD. You do not need to buy a new copy. Just use the same DVD and same Windows key.
2. After windows is installed and you are booted into it, now take an external drive and copy the files from the other PC which you backed up before in **PART ONE Step 4**.
3. Reinstall all applications, and now you have Windows working again and all your files too.
4. Don't install other OS like Linux until you know what you are doing, or let the professionals do it.